# Get all documents in collection that do not match criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a given query `criteria` which may or may not return some documents of a `collection`.
I want to get all the documents, that do not satisfy `criteria`.
So basically all the documents in `collection` that would not be found if I used `collection.find(criteria)`.

I have two approaches:

1. Negate the query. I tried `collection.find({$not: criteria})` which throws an error.
2. Get all documents and substract the documents, that match `criteria`: `collection.find()` \ `collection.find(criteria)`
   With "\" being the complement operator. - But I don't know how to do this.

Can you give me a code example in Javascript/Node?

Comment: What is the details of  `criteria` you mentioned? otherwise, you issue could be closed because it seems too board...

Comment: @zangw Could be anything build with https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors like `{
      $and: [
        {name: {$exists: true}},
        {url: {$exists: true}}]
    };
`

Comment: could be anything? maybe it is hard to answer your answer...

Comment: @zangw I have to treat the `criteria` as black box. I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

i think your query has to be like this:

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $nin: [ "value_1", "value_2" ] } } );
```

`$not` is for mixing with other comparison operators like:

```
db.inventory.find( { price: { $not: { $gt: 1.99 } } } )
```

Comment: This would work. But I can't change the given `criteria`. Im explicitly asking for what to do when I have a given `criteria`

Answer (score 0):

The error (whatever it might be) that is thrown when trying to use `$not` suggests you are not using it properly. The [Mongo $not documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) shows the following example:

> `db.inventory.find( { price: { $not: { $gt: 1.99 } } } )`

If your `criteria` is a complex query, this will not work. You would need to break it down into individual criteria per field, and apply it appropriately.

Alternatively, to find the set of items that is not present in another set (the *complement*), you can try something like the following:

```
var setA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
var setB = ['c', 'd', 'g'];

var complement = setA.filter(function (item) {
    return setB.indexOf(item) === -1;
});
```

For a more concrete implementation specific to Mongo, have a look at the [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference) operation, which:

> Takes two sets and returns an array containing the elements that only
>   exist in the first set

Comment: Is it possible to perform a complement operation on Cursors?

Comment: See additional comment above about $setDifference

Comment: isn't `$setDifference` only applicable on attributes (of a document) that are arrays?